# The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Приветствую! Делаю просто CRUD приложение, и столкнулся с проблемой update-а пользователей. При нажатии кнопки Save, вылетает ошибка "The requested resource is not available."

[image: Информация про ошибку и URL запроса]

Класс UserController

```
@Controller
public class UserControllerImpl implements UserController {

    private UserRepository repository;

    private UserValidator validator;

    @Autowired
    public UserControllerImpl(UserRepository repository, UserValidator validator) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Override
    public String getUsers(ModelMap model) {
        List<User> users = this.repository.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("user", users);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Override
    public String addUser(ModelMap model) {
        return "addUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Override
    public String addUser(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") String age, @RequestParam(value = "isAdmin",
            required = true, defaultValue = "false") Boolean isAdmin) {
        User user = new User(name, Integer.parseInt(age), isAdmin);
        user.setCreatedDate();
        this.repository.addUser(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "deleteUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Override
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        this.repository.removeUser(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "updateUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Override
    public String getUpdate(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userAttribute", this.repository.get(id));
        return "updateUser";
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans >


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.temaprof.app.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

update.jsp - конкретно он у меня и не работает полноценно

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update User</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/updateUser=${userAttribute.id}"/>
<form:form modelAttribute="userAttribute" method="post" action="${saveUrl}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">Id:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть еще index.jsp и addUser.jsp - в них всё работает корректно. 
Буду благодарен за помощь, если не хватает информации - пишите, что еще необходимо)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update User</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/updateUser/${userAttribute.id}"/>
<form:form modelAttribute="userAttribute" method="post" action="${saveUrl}">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="id">Id:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="id" disabled="true" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
    </tr>

    <%--<tr>--%>
        <%--<td><form:label path="isAdmin">Admin</form:label></td>--%>
        <%--<td><form:checkbox path="isAdmin"/></td>--%>
    <%--</tr>--%>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: как выглядит URL у страницы `index.jsp`?

Comment: localhost:8080/

Comment: это вы скопировали из браузера или руками набрали?

Comment: скопировал из браузера, но сейчас исправил вручную

Comment: http://localhost:8080/ - вот так выглядит, если скопировать из браузера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас **updateUser** ожидает **id** после **/**. А на картинке у вас **=**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Override
public String getUpdate(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userAttribute", this.repository.get(id));
    return "updateUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "updateUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Override
public String postUpdate(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userAttribute", this.repository.get(id));
    return "updateUser";
}
```

Comment: Изменил value="/updateUser=${userAttribute.id}" на value="/updateUser/${userAttribute.id}", не помогло, теперь вылетает ошибка  Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: где вы это изменили?

Comment: В updateUser.jsp

Comment: добавьте его в вопрос

Comment: Добавил. Пробовал добавить через ctrl + k, но код вставлялся только частично

Comment: замените GET на  POST

Comment: Заменил в контроллере GET на POST получил следующее - Request method 'GET' not supported

Comment: поскольку у вас Update должен реагировать и на GET, и на POST. то добавьте копию метода. я добавил ее в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Добавил метод, ошибку не выбивает, но обновление не происходит, просто обновляется страница с update - формой, можете подсказать в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Ок, тогда задам вопрос в новой теме. Спасибо за помощь!